# JSON to be stored in Realm

Tags: json, swift, realm

I have 2 issues on my app :

1/ After requested Api and fetched the Json in my app I need to store these datas by using Realm Data (my Realm Object didn't stored any properties at this moment).

2/ I also need to reuse the data stored in Realm in the case the user has no internet connexion).

Many thanks
Jay

My ApiRequest :

```
    class OpenWeatherApiHelper {
    static func getForecasts(completionHandler: @escaping ([Forecast]) -> ()) {

        Alamofire.request("http://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=6455259&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22").response { response in
            var forecasts = [Forecast]()


            //            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            //            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            //            print("Data: \(String(describing: response.data))")         // response data
            //            print("Error: \(String(describing: response.error))")       // response Error

            do {
                if let data = response.data
                    , let myJsons = try JSON(data: data).dictionary
                    , let lists = myJsons["list"]?.array {

                    let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ForecastQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

                    myQueue.async {
                        for (index, list) in lists.enumerated() {
                            if index % 8 == 0
                                , let dt = list["dt"].int
                                , let main = list["main"].dictionary
                                , let temp = main["temp"]?.int
                                , let tempMin = main["temp_min"]?.double
                                , let tempMax = main["temp_max"]?.double
                                , let pressure = main["pressure"]?.double
                                , let seaLevel = main["sea_level"]?.double
                                , let grndLevel = main["grnd_level"]?.double
                                , let tempKf = main["temp_kf"]?.int
                                , let humidity = main["humidity"]?.int
                                , let weathers = list["weather"].array
                                , let clouds = list["clouds"].dictionary
                                , let wind = list["wind"].dictionary
                                , let dtTxt = list["dt_txt"].string
                                , let all = clouds["all"]?.int
                                , let speed = wind["speed"]?.double
                                , let deg = wind["deg"]?.double
                            {
                                for weather in weathers {
                                    if let id = weather["id"].int
                                        , let main = weather["main"].string
                                        , let forecastDescription = weather["description"].string
                                        , let icon = weather["icon"].string {

                                        let forecast = Forecast(dt: dt, temp: temp, tempMin: tempMin, tempMax: tempMax, pressure: pressure, seaLevel: seaLevel, grndLevel: grndLevel, humidity: humidity, tempKf: tempKf, dtTxt: dtTxt, id: id, main: main, icon: icon, speed: speed, deg: deg, all: all, forecastDescription: forecastDescription)
                                        forecasts.append(forecast)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completionHandler(forecasts)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(forecasts)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Class Object :

```
class Forecast {
var dt: Int
var temp: Int
var tempMin: Double
var tempMax: Double
var pressure: Double
var seaLevel: Double
var grndLevel: Double
var humidity: Int
var tempKf: Int
var dtTxt: String
var id: Int
var main: String
var icon: String
var speed: Double
var deg: Double
var all: Int
var forecastDescription: String


init(dt: Int, temp: Int, tempMin: Double, tempMax: Double, pressure: Double, seaLevel: Double, grndLevel: Double, humidity: Int, tempKf: Int, dtTxt: String, id: Int, main: String, icon: String, speed: Double, deg: Double, all: Int, forecastDescription: String) {
    self.dt = dt
    self.temp = temp
    self.tempMin = tempMin
    self.tempMax = tempMax
    self.pressure = pressure
    self.seaLevel = seaLevel
    self.grndLevel = grndLevel
    self.humidity = humidity
    self.tempKf = tempKf
    self.dtTxt = dtTxt
    self.id = id
    self.main = main
    self.icon = icon
    self.speed = speed
    self.deg = deg
    self.all = all
    self.forecastDescription = forecastDescription
}
```

}

My Realm Class Object :

```
class RealmForecast: Object {
@objc dynamic var dt: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var temp: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var tempMin: Double = 0.0
@objc dynamic var tempMax: Double = 0.0
@objc dynamic var pressure: Double = 0.0
@objc dynamic var seaLevel: Double = 0.0
@objc dynamic var grndLevel: Double = 0.0
@objc dynamic var humidity: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var tempKf: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var dtTxt: String = ""
@objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var main: String = ""
@objc dynamic var icon: String = ""
@objc dynamic var speed: Double = 0.0
@objc dynamic var deg: Double = 0.0
@objc dynamic var all: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var forecastDescription: String = ""
```

}

In my VC :

```
    func updateDisplay() {
    OpenWeatherApiHelper.getForecasts { forecasts in
        self.forecasts = forecasts
        self.forecastTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func insert(forecast: RealmForecast) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write({
        let realmForecast = RealmForecast()
        realmForecast.all = forecast.all
        realmForecast.dt = forecast.dt
        realmForecast.temp = forecast.temp
        realmForecast.tempMin = forecast.tempMin
        realmForecast.tempMax = forecast.tempMax
        realmForecast.pressure = forecast.pressure
        realmForecast.seaLevel = forecast.seaLevel
        realmForecast.grndLevel = forecast.grndLevel
        realmForecast.humidity = forecast.humidity
        realmForecast.tempKf = forecast.tempKf
        realmForecast.dtTxt = forecast.dtTxt
        realmForecast.id = forecast.id
        realmForecast.main = forecast.main
        realmForecast.icon = forecast.icon
        realmForecast.speed = forecast.speed
        realmForecast.deg = forecast.deg
        realmForecast.all = forecast.all
        realmForecast.forecastDescription = forecast.forecastDescription

        realm.add(realmForecast)
    })
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateDisplay()
    let realmForecast = RealmForecast()

    insert(forecast: realmForecast)

}
```

}

Comment: There's no question here

Comment: Offtopic: why make 2 the same objects? Just use the realmcass

Comment: How to convert JSON and write in my Realm DB?

Comment: Dear Man you move on wrong way. You must make this code more effective.

Comment: @J.Doe bad advice

Comment: @epicpandaforce why is that?

Comment: @J.Doe oh, actually I think I was a bit overeager. Swift seems to make the user parse JSON completely manually. In Android world, you define a POJO, and the parser maps the fields over via reflection; but in that case, generally using API response POJO as RealmObject is bad practice.